# Concurrently update redux state in react

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have websocket connection which updates our redux state.but if no of message from websocket is more then it took time to update state one after another at the same time if we dispatch one action then it ill get execute after the websocket message get served. How can i achieve this concurrently ?

Comment: You can't concurrently update redux but you could buffer the updates in a middleware.

Comment: can u provide some example or some links

Comment: can this achieved using multiple stores ?